# Нужно вывести только те числа которые я перечислю

Tags: javascript

у меня есть код:

```
   var slash = document.getElementById("slash");
    var star = document.getElementById("star");
    var turn = document.getElementById("turn");

    var one = document.getElementById("one");
    var two = document.getElementById("two");
    var three = document.getElementById("three");
    var four = document.getElementById("four");
    var five = document.getElementById("five");
    var six = document.getElementById("six");
    var seven = document.getElementById("seven");
    var eight = document.getElementById("eight");
    var nine = document.getElementById("nine");

        if(quest == slash){
         var ceil = Math.random();

         if(ceil == 1) {
             one.innerHTML('/')
         }
```

и мне нужно через Math.random вывести числа от 1 до 9 так чтоб они не повторялись

Comment: p.s. `if(ceil == 1)` — это условие вообще никогда не выполнится. `Math.random()` выводит случайные числа от 0 (включительно) до 1 (не включительно). Никогда не выведет 1 (  )

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу и вам нужно сгенерировать 9 случайных чисел без повторов, то это можно сделать следующим образом:

```js
/**
 * Функция генерации случайного числа в заданном интервале.
 *
 * @param {number} min минимальное число
 * @param {number} max максимальное число
 * @return {number}
 */
function rand(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var result = [], number;
while (result.length < 9) {
    number = rand(1, 9);
    // Если такое число отсутствует, то добавляем его в массив
    if (result.indexOf(number) < 0) {
        result.push(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильным решением будет [Тасование_Фишера_—_Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0). Вкратце, вы берете **сразу** массив, заполнный от 1 до 9 и просто его перемешиваете по какому-либо алгоритму. В данном случае тем, что указано выше

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
console.log(shuffle(myArray));
```

Далее просто примените его к своей задаче.